# UITableView(with sqlite3) not update

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, sqlite

i'm korean my english so simple
very very sorry
please help me

my application example phone book.
two View and tab bar with sqlite3 DB

first view is table view cell list, there are name is linked DB
second view save and find and delete phone book list with SQL query.

i want secondview save data and change tab update data list.

i coded [viewDidAppear] reloadData method

close the application re-open apllication is updated.

but not updated change the tap T_T please help me.

**FirstViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "sqlite3.h"

@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>
{
    NSString *path;
    NSString *dbName;
    NSString *databasePath;
    sqlite3 *contactDB;
}
@property (nonatomic) sqlite3 *contactDB_2;
@property (strong,nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *myTable;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *quizs;

-(void)checkAndCreateDatabase;
-(void)readFromDatabase;

@end
```

**FistViewController.m**

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"
#import "person.h"

@implementation FirstViewController

@synthesize contactDB_2,myTable;
@synthesize quizs;

-(void)checkAndCreateDatabase{
NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
if([filemgr fileExistsAtPath:databasePath] == NO){
    const char *dbPath = [databasePath UTF8String];
    if(sqlite3_open(dbPath,&contactDB) == SQLITE_OK){
        char *errMsg;
        const char *sql_stmt = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CONTACTS(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,NAME TEXT,ADRESS TEXT, PHONE TEXT)";
        sqlite3_exec(contactDB, sql_stmt, NULL, NULL, &errMsg);
        sqlite3_close(contactDB);
    }
}
}
-(void)readFromDatabase
{
const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
sqlite3_stmt *statement;
if(sqlite3_open(dbpath, &contactDB)==SQLITE_OK)
{
    NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT name,phone FROM contacts"];
    const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(contactDB, query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL)==SQLITE_OK)
    {
        while(sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_ROW){
            NSString* nameField = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];
            NSString* phoneField = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)];

            person *persons = [person alloc];

            [persons setName:nameField];
            [persons setPhone:phoneField];

            [quizs addObject:persons];

        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        [myTable reloadData];
    }
    sqlite3_close(contactDB);
}
}
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"전화번호목록", @"전화번호목록");
    self.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"first"];
}
return self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
dbName = @"contacts2.db";
NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
databasePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:dbName];
[self checkAndCreateDatabase];
quizs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:100];
[self readFromDatabase];
[super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
[super viewDidUnload];
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
// e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;

}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
[myTable delegate];

}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewDidAppear:animated];
[quizs removeAllObjects];
[self checkAndCreateDatabase];
[self readFromDatabase];
[myTable reloadData];
}


- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
// Return YES for supported orientations
return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

-(NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
return 1;
}
-(NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return quizs.count;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString* cellIdentifier = @"cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

if(cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

}
person *p = [quizs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSString *str = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@ %@",p.name,p.phone];
cell.textLabel.text = str;

return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
NSInteger row = indexPath.row;

NSString *temp = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%d번쨰꺼 선택해뜸",row+1];

UIAlertView *alert =[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"터치" message:temp delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"확인", nil];

[alert show];
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}

@end
```

## I want change the tab and update cell list.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can not  insert the data in database in background .So until all data are inserted you have to keep application alive. If all data are saved successfully then please write reloadData code in ViewWillAppear.